# MMS After obtaining the address, the download failed

Tags: android

I have obtained the attachment address but the download timeout.
This is my code.

public class MmsSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String MMS_RECEIVE_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED";

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(MMS_RECEIVE_ACTION)) {
        PduParser parser = new PduParser(intent.getByteArrayExtra("data"));
        NotificationInd genericPdu = (NotificationInd) parser.parse();
        byte[] data=genericPdu.getContentLocation();
        try {
           String url=new String(data);
            Log.e("download url",url);
            final byte mms[]= HttpUtils.httpConnection(context,-1L,url,null,HttpUtils.HTTP_GET_METHOD,true, "10.0.0.172", 80);
            Log.e("download length", String.valueOf(mms.length));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This is mostly code, you need to review how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry，this is my first question i will revise